# HTML5 Canvas - Best practice for moving objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a game using  and JavaScript.  The game will involve the player navigating through a dungeon.  My question is what is the best way to code objects like walls, doors etc?  I'm stuck between two obvious choices

1. Draw every object onto the canvas and move the objects based on how the player moves
2. Have all of the object pre drawn onto a background image and just move the background image according to how the player moves

I'm thinking option 2 will be easier but I'll still have to detect where the objects are so the player can't just walk over a wall.

Basically I want to know if anyone can speak from experience about the best way to design the game and are there any resources on this?

Comment: If you are more interested in making a game than making an engine maybe consider using an existing framework such as http://phaser.io/ or http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS I believe both of these use the concept of a camera to move objects. If you are interested in not using a framework/engine you could still look into how others have implemented a camera so you could position all your objects within in the world and move the camera through the world.

Comment: Yes, #2 is easier and will have better performance. You need to do some research into "tile based collision detection" to help you detect walls and objects. ... but here are the basics: 1) Your walls/objects are in a 2D map array. 2) You convert the sprite's xy screen coordinates into a map array index number with a custom getIndex() function. 3) If the sprite's location in the array is the same as a wall or object, you have a collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance requirements for your role-playing game are less than, for example, an arcade game.

You will probably be ok just redrawing everything in their new positions.

But even so, you gain performance by having your background (that moves infrequently) on a separate layer than your often moving character.

A layer can be as simple as a background img element that is moved by CSS or can be a separate background-canvas that is layered under a top player-canvas.

The good news is that you can start out with a single layer and then fairly easily change to multiple layers if performance becomes an issue.

There's not a "best way to design a game" but here's some advice:

- Get a tiny working prototype running very soon in the project.
- Make incremental changes to the prototype.
- test, test, test...

Disclaimer: I don't design games, but I do design quality-control applications that use many of the same interactive technologies used in gaming.